# Select records which contains list of words from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the [Product] Table.

I want to select records from [Product] that contain words listed in Table_B.

| id | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC Voucher |
| 2 | Vitamin Generator |
| 3 | Dark Chocolate |
| 4 | Fast Charge |
| 5 | Remote Controller |
| 6 | Power Generator |
| 7 | LED TV |

Following is Table_B (Which contains a list of Words)

| WordList |
| --- |
| Generator |
| Fast |
| Controller |

**Required Output:**

| Sr | Full_List |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Vitamin Generator |
| 4 | Fast Charge |
| 5 | Remote Controller |
| 6 | Power Generator |

For easy, following is the SQL Code for sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #products

CREATE TABLE #products (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #products (id, ProductName)
VALUES
  (1, 'ABC Voucher'),
  (2, 'Vitamin Generator'),
  (3, 'Dark Chocolate'),
  (4, 'Fast Charge'),
  (5, 'Remote Controller'),
  (6, 'Power Generator'),
  (7, 'LED TV');
```

- 

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table_B

CREATE TABLE #Table_B (
    WordList VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Table_B (WordList)
VALUES
  ('Generator'),
  ('Fast'),
  ('Controller');
```

Like operator with "or" in Where condition will not work in my case as list is dynamic and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXISTS in combination with LIKE to achieve what you need.

```
 SELECT * FROM #products p
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (
    SELECT * FROM #Table_B b 
    WHERE p.ProductName LIKE '%' + b.WordList + '%'
)
```

Comment: This kind of works. It certainly works great for the simple example shown. But it can return false positives also. I guess that depends on if the OP is ok with partial matches or they need entire words.

Comment: In Table_B which contains Word list will always have a single word per row

Answer (score -2):

```sql
SELECT id, ProductName 
FROM Product 
where ProductName IN 
(SELECT WordList FROM Table_B)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?